# composer and php installation conflict for laravel 4 artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

hi i start working Laravel 4, i have finished the installation process with composer, but when try to use artisan it always give a message

**Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension**

i have checked with php_info() it shows me Mcrypt PHP extension is enabled, after searching on web i have found some solutions, if i apply those then composer stops working viceversa . i am using XAMPP for development if i use **which php** command in terminal it show me path **/usr/bin/php** but my development php is in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin**, i have extend the $PATH using .bash_profile

```
export XAMPP_PHP=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH="$XAMPP_PHP:$PATH"
```

after this artisan start work great but composer stops its working if i type composer command in terminal it show ???? output, now i want composer, php and artisan work perfect just looking for good settings

Comment: are you sure you have PHP >=5.3.7? Also - run PHPInfo - does it show mcrypt in there?

Comment: well on xampp i have php 5.3.1 and on native Mac osx php is 5.3.8

Comment: sorry on Mac os PHP version is 5.3.15 but Mcrypt PHP extension is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it outputs ???? it most likely means you have `detect_unicode = On` in your php.ini. This must be off because it breaks phar files.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a workaround. Instead of changing the $PATH variable, on **/usr/bin/** I created a symbolic link to XAMPP's PHP:

```
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php phpx
```

'phpx' is the name I gave to run php on XAMPP (pick the name you prefer - *obviously it needs to be different than 'php'*). This way I can run artisan using 'phpx' (XAMPP version) which has mcrypt. For example:

```
phpx artisan key:generate
```

And if you need to run composer, you run php (mac version):

```
php composer.phar install
```

It's a workaround, I'm not proud of it, but it's working.

The best solution would be to install mcrypt on your mac (use [this tutorial](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/)), mysql and use mac's php. But as a lot of developers (including me) still rely on XAMPP, this workaround may be enough for testing.